# Clean log files

Tags: log

I have these log files:

```
72K     /var/log/dist-upgrade
4.0K    /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
4.0K    /var/log/samba/cores/nmbd
12K     /var/log/samba/cores
84K     /var/log/samba
44K     /var/log/gdm
4.0K    /var/log/bittorrent
1.6M    /var/log/installer
4.0K    /var/log/asterisk/cdr-custom
19M     /var/log/asterisk/cdr-csv
1.2G    /var/log/asterisk
4.0K    /var/log/apparmor
4.0K    /var/log/unattended-upgrades
36K     /var/log/cups
4.0K    /var/log/news
120K    /var/log/proftpd
12K     /var/log/fsck
28K     /var/log/apt
1.2G    /var/log
```

Could I please get some help cleaning these log files?

Comment: Is this `du` output? Or something else? Can you fix the formatting so it's readable?

Comment: Asterisk logging is pretty [well documented](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Logging).

Comment: Normally your system will run logrotate to move and compress logs over a certain size. Logrotate keeps a configured number of each logs, and delete old ones automatically. If some logfile grows a lot. you should look in to that file and fix the problem - if any.

Comment: question: why?  The largest outside of asterisk is 120K. and see the link Jos posted on that.

Answer (score 2):

Simple log cleanning

```
sudo /etc/cron.daily/logrotate

# optionnal, delete log archives
sudo find /var/log -type f -iname *.gz -delete
```

Find more about freeing disk space on root partition : https://askubuntu.com/a/1161181/77093

Comment: This returns the following on Ubuntu:

`
find: paths must precede expression: apport.log.3.gz'
find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate -iname'?
`

Answer (score 0):

by clean do you mean remove/delete?

if so then this has already been answered:

- [How do I delete var/log files in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077578/how-do-i-delete-var-log-files-in-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus)
- [Can I delete /var/log files due to low root space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171678/can-i-delete-var-log-files-due-to-low-root-space)
- [Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do)

As described in those answers, to delete all logs open terminal, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and run:

```
sudo rm /var/log/*
```

to delete a specific log file run:

```
sudo rm /var/log/*nameoflogfile*.log
```

Although as stated in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/515152/1123252) answer, it is also worth checking through the logs to find out what exactly is causing your logs to grow so large.

Comment: "sudo rm /var/log/*| No. You do `> /var/log/{logfile}` There are services that are active that require the log file to be present.